# No instance for (Floating Int) (Fractional Int)

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-platform

Here is part of my code:

```
sqa = a*a 
sqb = b*b
endX = (/) (fromIntegral sqa) (sqrt (fromIntegral (sqa + sqb)))
```

and both `a` and `b` are `Int`. However, after I use `fromIntegral` on it, it still shows errors `No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of 'sqrt'` and `No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of '/'`. I don't know why this happens. Can anyone help me?

More context:

```
ellipse :: (Int, Int) -> Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int), Double]
ellipse (xc, yc) a b = plotEllipse1 (xc, yc, xi, yi, di1)
where
   sqa = a*a
   sqb = b*b
   xi = 0
   yi = b
   di1 = 2*sqb - 2*b*sqa + sqa
   endX = (/) (fromIntegral sqa) (sqrt (fromIntegral (sqa + sqb)))
   plotEllipse1 :: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Raster
   plotEllipse1 (x0, y0, curX, curY, curD)
     | curX > endX  = plotEllipse2 (xc, yc, curX, curY, di2)
     | otherwise = ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Also please show a [mcve]. The code you posted here gives a different compiler error than the one you are asking about because there is no `main`.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me.

Comment: It's part of codes in where clause, which I need to compute the result of endX.

Comment: Please edit your original question with the missing code.

Comment: I've added more codes. I hope it's easier for you to find the problem.

Comment: Please post an MCVE - something people can copy and paste to see your same error and avoid guessing what `Raster` and `Coord` actually mean.

Answer (score 3):

`plotEllipse1` takes a tuple of `Int`s:

```hs
plotEllipse1 :: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Raster
```

`curX` is one of the elements of the tuple, so it's an `Int`:

```hs
plotEllipse1 (x0, y0, curX, curY, curD)
```

You compare `curX` to `endX` using `>`:

```hs
  | curX > endX  = plotEllipse2 (xc, yc, curX, curY, di2)
```

`>` is type `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, which means that the left and right sides must be the same type.

`endX`'s type is in the `Fractional` and `Floating` typeclasses because you use `sqrt` and `/` to obtain it. But remember, the left and right sides of `>` must be the same type, so `curX` has to also have a type with those typeclasses, but *its type, `Int`, definitely isn't part of those typeclasses*, which the error messages are complaining about.

So, how do we fix this? We convert `curX` to `endX`'s type:

```hs
  | fromIntegral curX > endX  = plotEllipse2 (xc, yc, curX, curY, di2)
```

Now `fromIntegral curX` should have the appropriate type.

---

Notice also that you've used `fromIntegral` elsewhere. You simply missed it in one more place it was needed.

You may also need to give `endX` a type signature so that the compiler knows *which* `Fractional` and `Floating` type you want to use. For example, `Double` is a perfectly good candidate, so maybe you'll use:

```hs
endX :: Double
endX = (/) (fromIntegral sqa) (sqrt (fromIntegral (sqa + sqb)))
```

Comment: After I' ve done this  | curX > fromIntegral endX  = plotEllipse2 (xc, yc, curX, curY, di2), a new error occured: "Ambiguous type variable 'a0' arising from a use of 'fromIntegral'.

Comment: Try the last two paragraphs I just added to my answer. That should help that, but we'll see.

Comment: It shows "No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of 'fromIntegral'" now.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused a little when writing the answer. Try switching the `fromIntegral` to the other side of the `>`, as shown above in the new version of the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to, try to learn what the type errors were telling you along the way. It'll help in future encounters with them.

Comment: Stylistically, its possible to infix `(/)` operator: `endX = (...) / (...)`